# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a sample ASP.NET MVC web application, and I'm following code-first approach for the database. I want to create `products` table and `transactions` table, and additionally I want to include some sample data through migrations, but when I tried to do `Update-Database` I got the error message mentioned in the title. I know exactly why the error happens, and that's because I use `List<Product>`, as can be seen below. But, I don't know how can I solve the problem, while transactions should include one or more products. My code segments can be found below.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

I also added the following lines of code in `IdentityModels.cs` file:

```
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
```

Lastly, my `Configuration.cs` file which holds the migrations, looks like this:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}

protected override void Seed(MyApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    var pr = new List<Product>();
    pr.Add(new Product { Name = "Book" });
    pr.Add(new Product { Name = "Table" });
    pr.Add(new Product { Name = "Chair" });

    pr.ForEach(i => context.Products.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, i));
    context.SaveChanges();

    context.Transactions.AddOrUpdate(
        t => t.Products,
        new Transaction { Products = new List<Product>(pr.Where(p => p.Name == "Book" || p.Name == "Table")) },
        new Transaction
        {
            Products = new List<Product>(pr.Where(p => p.Name == "Chair" || p.Name == "Book" || p.Name == "Table"))
        }
    );

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Try making your properties virtual and using an `ICollection` instead of a `List<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first parameter of `AddOrUpdate` method, i.e `identifierExpression`. You should provide a primitive type there, which determines when you want update and when to add. If a row in the database matches the `identifierExpression` it will updated with the new one you provided. If not, the new one will be inserted to the database.

You used `t.Products` as identifier which means, the update should take place when the one you are adding has `Products` identical with one of the database rows, which cannot be correct because `Products` has not a primitive type. So you can provide a primitive type property or do not use this parameter at all(which means all of the items will be inserted).

```
context.Transactions.AddOrUpdate(
    //t => t.Products,   //comment this
    new Transaction { 
        Products = new List<Product>(
                        pr.Where(p => p.Name == "Book" || p.Name == "Table")) 
    },
    new Transaction
    {
        Products = new List<Product>(
                pr.Where(p => p.Name == "Chair" || p.Name == "Book" || p.Name == "Table"))
    }
);
```

**Suggestion**

From your `Seed` method one can infer that the relationship between `Transaction` and `Product` is many to many. If it is the case, you should specify it for EF. Based on your current model, the relation is one to many.
You can change it like this(in the `Context` class):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().HasMany(x => x.Products).WithMany();
}
```

On a side note, if you want to add lazy loading to your model, you should declare `Products` property of `Transaction` as `virtual`.

Comment: Now, the `update-database` succeeds, but in my `transactions` table I only have `TransactionID`, and not the `Products` column. And It has created a new column in `products` table, named `Transaction_TransactionID`, whose values are also not quite right. I wanted the `transaction` table to include the `TransactionID` and the list of products used for that specific transaction. Any idea?

Comment: See the suggestion I added.

Comment: When, I add that function inside my  `ApplicationDbContext`, I get multiple errors on `update-database` or any other command related to migrations and database. One of the errors is "IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType".